# 503 Errors with Apache httpd and Tomcat and mod_spdy

Tags: apache, http-status-code-503, spdy, mod-spdy

I run a server which uses httpd and an AJP proxy to Tomcat.

I switched on mod_spdy on my server yesterday and I started seeing some 503 errors. I have read something that because of the number of parallels connections through mod_spdy it may cause an issue. Is this the case and how do you resolve this?